# my database path in "Data Source=F:\databas1.mdf; How to set database connection in c# website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below My Database connection path but I can't connect to database

```
 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.F:\Database.mdf");   
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM stu1", cn);  
 SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);  
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 adp.Fill(ds);  
 GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];   
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: there is a '.' before F:\ make sure first that is not the problem

Comment: What is the error are you getting???

Answer (score 1):

A great resource I always keep around is [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com).
It's really handy for finding these connection strings when you can't find an example.

Particularly [this page](http://connectionstrings.com/?carrier=sqlserver2005) applied to your problem

**Attach a database file on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance**

```
Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=F:\Database.mdf"; Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Comment: i can't do this ,give me a simply & easy solution

Comment: @manthan Just your connection string is missing. Go to http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005 and find the suitable string according to your database and use it.You need to pass the whole connection string in `SqlConnection', just passing `Data Source` won't work.

Comment: i applied below     code in        sqlconnection ....        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Server=.\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=F:\\Database.mdf;Database=Database.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your code, as per your database:

```
 connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB Name;User ID=sa;Password=test";


 SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM stu1", ConnectionString);  
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 adp.Fill(ds, "stu1");  
 GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];   
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

Try this out and let me know if you face any issue. I hope it will help you to resolve your issue. :)

Comment: can't work your code,my sql database in F: drive,so give me simply and easy solution...